# While-function for mysqli_fetch_assoc is infinite

Tags: php, session

I have two HTML pages inside a session. On my first page, I want to create an array, which is saved in a $_SESSION variable. On the second page, I want to display my array.

PHP code for my first page looks like that:

```
<?php
  include ("../script/db_connect.php");

  $select_questions = 'select * from questions ';

  if (isset($_POST["own"]) && $_POST["own"] == "No") {
    $select_questions .= 'where creator != '
                       . $_SESSION["id"];
  }

  $select_questions .= 'limit 3';

  $questions_result = mysqli_query($con, $select_questions);

  $_SESSION["questions"] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($questions_result);

  mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

PHP code on my second page looks like that:

```
<?php while ($array = $_SESSION["questions"]) {
       echo $array["question"]; } ?>
```

When I go to second page, an infinite loop is displayed, where only the first element of my array is displayed over and over again. What is the reason for that? I cannot find any mistake in my code.

Comment: Do `$array = array_shift($_SESSION["questions"])` else it will aways set the value new with the same data and that becomes infiniti.

Comment: But why are you using `while` if you are only fetch on row with `mysqli_fetch_assoc($questions_result)`?  Right would be `while ($array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($questions_result))`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change this

`$_SESSION["questions"] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($questions_result);`

to (here we fetch all rows from the sql result, not only one)

`while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($questions_result)) $_SESSION["questions"][] = $row;`

And later do

`foreach($_SESSION["questions"] as $quest) { echo $quest["question"]; }`

Comment: This one works better, but some entries are displayed more than once. So at the end I don't get 3 rows (row 1, row 2, row 3), but 6 rows (row 1, row 1, row 2, row 3, row 1, row 2).

The order is pretty weird.

Comment: @sebjel1 Thing it has to do with the use of the SESSION varaible, did you empty it before refill it? Why using $_SESSION at this point? Rething your logic, my code examples in the answer are fully ok. Downvoter has no brain.

Comment: Thank you, my problem was, that I didn't empty my $_SESSION variable. Thanks!